# After resolve merge conflicts changes in git and commit it,It used another user as a author

Tags: git

my local user is user A and I cherry-pick the commit in another branch. that commit author is user B.When cherry-picking (as user A) I got some conflicts.I(user A) resolve that conflicts and committed it locally. but the commit history shows the commit author as user B.I can't imagine this. Without cherry-picking(local changes committing) It works correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git` stores one author name and one committer name per commit.  If you run the command that creates a new commit object, your local settings should dictate the committer.

But in general when the command copies another commit, the author is copied (unchanged) from that other commit as well (as you should expect; just because you cherry-pick a commit doesn't mean you wrote the changes it introduces).

With rebase or cherry-pick in particular, it's possible that a single commit introduces changes by multiple authors, and then git still has to identify a single author.  In this case, there's the author of the original content being copied, and the author of any conflict resolutions.  It seems reasonable that git would assume the conflict resolution is comparatively minor.  So while you can't imagine it working the way it does, I can't imagine it re-crediting the underlying changes of the commit to the person who merely re-committed them.

In the case of an interactive rebase using `squash` commands, the metadata seems to be taken from the earlier commit involved in the operation.  That seems like a more egregious assumption to me, but I guess the idea is that you're probably combining a group of related changes (i.e. common case might be a single user collapsing a local branch before sharing), and if you need to keep track of who did which change when then you wouldn't squash the commits.

The `--squash` option to the `merge` command, on the other hand, treats the resulting commit as newly authored by the person running the `--squash` command (more like the behavior you seem to expect) - *but* by default it preserves the authorship of each original commit in the new commit's message.

So looking at all that, the take-away is: don't take the author metadata too seriously.  It's a nice tool if you need a hint that "so-and-so might know something about this code"; it is *not* a 100% reliable way to assign credit for work done, and it certainly isn't "evidence" of who did what (i.e. if you need a way to audit, after the fact, that UserA signed off on change X, then you need something else, like signatures).

Comment: Minor addition: In order to see both the committer/author information for an example commit `ada4440`, you could use e.g.:
`git log -1 --pretty="format:%h, Author: %an, Committer: %cn" ada4440`
or `git cat-file -p ada4440`

Comment: @JayaniSumudini - If you can't get past using author info to blame someone for the problem, then don't use commands that mix changes from multiple authors into one commit I guess.